# Java Security - RSA Public Key & Private Key Code Issue

Tags: java, security, encryption, rsa

Here is my error

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big.
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(Unknown Source)
    at com.sanjaya.rsa.PublicKeyReader.get(PublicKeyReader.java:22)
    at com.sanjaya.rsa.MainKeyClass.main(MainKeyClass.java:8)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big.
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Here is my code - **MAIN CLASS**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PublicKeyReader publicKeyReader=new PublicKeyReader();
    try {
        publicKeyReader.get("c:\\public.key");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PrivateKeyReader privateKeyReader=new PrivateKeyReader();
    try {
        privateKeyReader.get("c:\\private.key");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is public key related method

```
  public static PublicKey get(String filename) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec =new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePublic(spec);
  }
```

Here is private key related method

```
  public static PrivateKey get(String filename)throws Exception {
    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec =new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
  }
```

Please help me to sort out this issue

Need to create public key & private key & Encrypt ,decrypt string from those under RSA encyption

Comment: Probably the wrong file format. How did you create the key files?

Comment: its sent by third party.but unable to open in notepad also.
is that reason for the above error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;

class RSA{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    generateKeys();
    rsaEncrypt("plaintext.txt", "encrypted.txt");
    rsaDecrypt("encrypted.txt", "decrypted.txt");
}

public static void generateKeys() throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    PublicKey publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    PrivateKey privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

    System.out.println("keys created");

    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKeySpec pub = fact.getKeySpec(publicKey,
            RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
    RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = fact.getKeySpec(privateKey,
            RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

    saveToFile("public.key", pub.getModulus(), pub.getPublicExponent());
    saveToFile("private.key", priv.getModulus(), priv.getPrivateExponent());

    System.out.println("keys saved");
}

public static void saveToFile(String fileName, BigInteger mod,
        BigInteger exp) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream fileOut = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
    try {
        fileOut.writeObject(mod);
        fileOut.writeObject(exp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected error");
    } finally {
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.println("Closed writing file.");
    }
}

// Return the saved key
static Key readKeyFromFile(String keyFileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(keyFileName);
    ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
            in));
    try {
        BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
        BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        if (keyFileName.startsWith("public"))
            return fact.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e));
        else
            return fact.generatePrivate(new RSAPrivateKeySpec(m, e));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
    } finally {
        oin.close();
        System.out.println("Closed reading file.");
    }
}

// Use this PublicKey object to initialize a Cipher and encrypt some data
public static void rsaEncrypt(String file_loc, String file_des)
        throws Exception {
    FileReader file = new FileReader("C://myprograms//plaintext.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
    String text = "";
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while(line!= null)
    {
        text += line;
    line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();
    System.out.println(text);
    byte[] data = new byte[32];
    int i;

    System.out.println("start encyption");
    Key pubKey = readKeyFromFile("public.key");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file_loc);
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file_des);
    CipherOutputStream cipherOut = new CipherOutputStream(fileOut, cipher);

    // Read in the data from the file and encrypt it
    while ((i = fileIn.read(data)) != -1) {
        cipherOut.write(data, 0, i);
    }

    // Close the encrypted file
    cipherOut.close();
    fileIn.close();

    System.out.println("encrypted file created");
}

// Use this PublicKey object to initialize a Cipher and decrypt some data
public static void rsaDecrypt(String file_loc, String file_des)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] data = new byte[32];
    int i;

    System.out.println("start decyption");

    Key priKey = readKeyFromFile("private.key");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, priKey);

    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file_loc);
    CipherInputStream cipherIn = new CipherInputStream(fileIn, cipher);
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file_des);

    // Write data to new file
    while ((i = cipherIn.read()) != -1) {
        fileOut.write(i);
    }

    // Close the file
    fileIn.close();
    cipherIn.close();
    fileOut.close();

    System.out.println("decrypted file created");

}
}
```

This program encrypts the text in plaintext.txt file and saves the cipher text in encrypted.txt file. Similarly decryption is done using encrypted.txt file and plain text is saved in decrypted.txt file .#

Answer (score 0):

Check the cert file's newline characters! I had a cert with Unix-style newline chars. I was attempting to use gradle to bundle my cert into a WAR, and I was also having gradle do some string replacements on the files in my WAR. However, gradle was converting everything it processed to Windows-style newline chars. This caused the InvalidKeyException. Excluding my cert files from gradle's processing fixed the problem:

```
webInf {
    from myProjectFiles eachFile { projectFile
        if (!projectFile.path.contains( myCertFiles ) {
            filter { line ->
                line.replace(someKey, someValue)
            }
        }
    }
archiveName = 'myProject.war'
```